# Index mysql key select

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, query-optimization, explain

I need help for performance this query

```
SELECT *
 FROM transactions 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2022-08-25 01:03:21' AND '2022-12-13 01:03:21'
 AND ((transaction_reason IN ('ORIGINAL','REVERSAL_OF_ADJUSTMENT') 
 AND type = 'DEPOSIT') 
OR (transaction_reason IN ('ADJUSTMENT','REVERSAL_OF_ORIGINAL') 
 AND type = 'WITHDRAWAL') )
ORDER BY transaction_id ASC
```

primary key: ID

foreign key: transaction_id

explain

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | transactions |  | ALL | idx_transactions_dd |  |  |  | 18356060 | 18.00 | Using where; Using filesort |

key is null, my index is idx_transactions_dd (created_at,transaction_reason, type)

any advice?

i need create a new index or modify the query

Answer (score 1):

Since `IN` is equivalent to `OR`, further split up the query with `UNION`.

Change from `UNION` to `UNION ALL` assuming there won't be any dups.

This index will be optimal for all 3 Selects:

```
INDEX(type, transaction_reason, created_at)
```

The UNION:

```
( SELECT *
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE type = 'DEPOSIT' 
      AND transaction_reason = 'ORIGINAL'
      AND created_at BETWEEN '2022-08-25 01:03:21' AND '2022-12-13 01:03:21'
) UNION ALL
( SELECT *
    FROM transactions 
    WHERE type = 'DEPOSIT' 
      AND transaction_reason = 'REVERSAL_OF_ADJUSTMENT'
      AND created_at BETWEEN '2022-08-25 01:03:21' AND '2022-12-13 01:03:21'
) UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM transactions
    WHERE type = 'WITHDRAWAL'
      AND transaction_reason IN ('ADJUSTMENT', 'REVERSAL_OF_ORIGINAL')
) 
ORDER BY transaction_id ASC;
```

(I added parentheses to clarify that you wanted the `ORDER BY` to apply to the result of the `UNION`, not to the last `SELECT`.)

Comment: Great breakup.  Only thing I would comment on to the user is that the withdrawls in their original did not have the date/time context.  So your query (and the original) will get all deposits within the date range in question, but pull ALL withdrawls of given reason regardless of the date.  They probably want the same time period in question as the others.

Comment: @DRapp - Sure.  (I noticed that anomaly.)  Use 4 SELECTs in the UNION.

Answer (score 0):

You need indexes on the columns `(type, created_at)` and `(type, transaction_reason)`.

Then refactor the query. Instead of using `OR` in your WHERE clause, run two queries and `UNION` their respective results:

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions 
WHERE type = 'DEPOSIT' 
 AND created_at BETWEEN '2022-08-25 01:03:21' AND '2022-12-13 01:03:21'
 AND transaction_reason IN ('ORIGINAL','REVERSAL_OF_ADJUSTMENT'))
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE type = 'WITHDRAWAL'
 AND transaction_reason IN ('ADJUSTMENT','REVERSAL_OF_ORIGINAL') 
ORDER BY transaction_id ASC;
```

You can't optimize both `BETWEEN` and `IN` in the same WHERE clause. Both are range conditions. An index can support only one range condition (though there is now some support of [skip scan range optimization in MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-skip-scan)).

Comment: ty, times decreased from 1h to 8min, the table has millions of records

Comment: Did the EXPLAIN improve? I think it should show `type: ref` for both queries, and a lower value in the `rows` column.

Comment: # id select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra 
1 PRIMARY transactions  range  idx_transfer_createdtype 1029  9178030 20 Using index condition; Using where 
2 UNION transactions  range  idx_transfer_createdreason 2046  7053 100 Using index condition 
 UNION RESULT <union1,2>  ALL       Using temporary; Using filesort

ref is null in this case

Comment: That's the EXPLAIN report I would expect. Good job!